# Dual sim api (like Dual Sim Control)

Tags: android, dual-sim

I need to develop an application to enable data of a dual-sim android phone.

For example, sometimes I need to enable data on the first sim, and other times for the second sim.

I discovered an api called [mediatek](http://labs.mediatek.com/site/global/developer_tools/mediatek_android/documentation/index.gsp)
It is an api that allows us to manipulate dual sim. I take a look on the playstore, and then I found the application 
 [Dual Sim Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pt.joaormf.mtkcontrol.free) which allow us to manipulate sim card of the phone.

When I look at the api reference of mediatek, I only see some method to get the sim card information but no method to change the sim information.

I need your help to enable or disable data on the dual sim android phone baseed on mediatek processor.

Thanks